# I want my Python functions to accept numpy ndarrays

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I'm writing a script to plot a 3D representation of some thermodynamic property, Z = f(pr, Tr). pr and Tr are created with `[numpy.]arange()` and then they are mapped with `[numpy.]meshgrid()` the following way:

```
    Tr = arange(1.0, 2.6, 0.10)
    pr = arange(0.5, 9.0, 0.25)
    Xpr, YTr = meshgrid(pr, Tr)
```

Xpr and YTr are then passed to the function that calculates the aforementioned property:

```
    Z = function(Xpr, YTr)
```

("function" is just a generic name that is later replaced by the actual function name).

The values stored in Z are finally plotted:

```
    fig = plt.figure(1, figsize=(7, 6))
    ax = fig.add_subplot(projection='3d')
    surf = ax.plot_surface(Xpr, YTr, Z, cmap=cm.jet, linewidth=0, antialiased=False)
```

Everything works fine when "function" is something quite straightforward like:

```
def zshell(pr_, Tr_):
    A = -0.101 - 0.36*Tr_ + 1.3868*sqrt(Tr_ - 0.919)
    B = 0.021 + 0.04275/(Tr_ - 0.65)
    E = 0.6222 - 0.224*Tr_
    F = 0.0657/(Tr_ - 0.85) - 0.037
    G = 0.32*exp(-19.53*(Tr_ - 1.0))
    D = 0.122*exp(-11.3*(Tr_ - 1.0))
    C = pr_*(E + F*pr_ + G*pr_**4)

    z = A + B*pr_ + (1.0 - A)*exp(-C) - D*(pr_/10.0)**4

    return z
```

But it fails when the function is something like this:

```
def zvdw(pr_, Tr_):
    A = 0.421875*pr_/Tr_**2     # 0.421875 = 27.0/64.0
    B = 0.125*pr_/Tr_           # 0.125 = 1.0/8.0

    z = 9.5e-01
    erro = 1.0

    while erro >= 1.0e-06:
        c2 = -(B + 1.0)
        c1 = A
        c0 = -A*B
        f = z**3 + c2*z**2 + c1*z + c0
        df = 3.0e0*z**2 + 2.0e0*c2*z + c1
        zf = z - f/df
        erro = abs((zf - z)/z)
        z = zf

    return z
```

I strongly suspect that the failure is caused by the iterative method inside function `zvdw(pr_, Tr_)` (`zvdw` has been previously tested and works perfectly well when float arguments are passed to it). That is the error message I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/home/fausto/.../TestMesh.py", line 81, in <module>
    Z = zvdw(Xpr, YTr)

  File "/home/fausto/.../TestMesh.py", line 63, in zvdw
    while erro >= 1.0e-06:

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Yet the error message doesn't seem (to me) to be directly related to the `while` statement.

Any ideas?

Comment: `zf` and `z` are 2 dimensional arrays inside while loop. after `erro = abs((zf - z)/z)` `erro` is also 2 dimensional. after one loop `erro >= 1.0e-06` will be a 2 dimensional array with truth values, possibly both `True` and `False`. Thats were the error message comes from. What should be the condition to end the while loop? Every value equals `False`, most of them or is one enough?

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny, thanks for the enlightenment. I would say that one ```False``` should be enough, but maybe I'm being too hasty in my judgement. What should I do, supposing I'm right?

Comment: `while all(erro >= 1.0e-06):` where `all` should be the `numpy.all` function, not the python function. If you want to work with `numpy` you should look into `np.all` and `np.any`. To avoid confusion you should use the common way to import `numpy` with `import numpy as np`.

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny, that worked, and ```while (erro >= 1.0e-06).all():``` also works. But first I had to redefine the initial value of ```erro```from ```erro = 1.0``` to ```erro = array(1.0)```. Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 1):

### Tl;dr

There is a `numpy` functionality for that. You just replace

```
def zvdw(pr_, Tr_):
```

by

```
@np.vectorize
def zvdw(pr_, Tr_):
```

And it works.

### Get it faster

Unfortunately the resulting picture looked ugly since your mesh is to sparse. I replaced your step size in `TR` and `pr`. Unfortunately here we run into the limitation of `np.vectorize`. From the numpy documentation

> The vectorize function is provided primarily for convenience, not for
> performance. The implementation is essentially a for loop.

I.e. it is painfully slow. Already at 0.0010 and 0.0025 it took 17.5 seconds. So it is not realistic to go a factor of 10 each smaller since that would take ~100 times longer. Fortunately your code is simple enough that I can use `@numba.vectorize` which on my machine was a factor of ~23 faster.

Notice that this only works for some python code. Numba compiles the python code to llvm code so it can run fast. But it is unable to do that for arbitrary python code. See https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/user/vectorize.html

And here is your picture
[image]

### Code seems not to work with `np.vectorize/numba.vectorize`

That is very odd. Here is a literal copy paste of code that works on my machine:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

Tr = np.arange(1.0, 2.6, 0.10)
pr = np.arange(0.5, 9.0, 0.25)
Xpr, YTr = np.meshgrid(pr, Tr)

def zshell(pr_, Tr_):
    A = -0.101 - 0.36*Tr_ + 1.3868*sqrt(Tr_ - 0.919)
    B = 0.021 + 0.04275/(Tr_ - 0.65)
    E = 0.6222 - 0.224*Tr_
    F = 0.0657/(Tr_ - 0.85) - 0.037
    G = 0.32*exp(-19.53*(Tr_ - 1.0))
    D = 0.122*exp(-11.3*(Tr_ - 1.0))
    C = pr_*(E + F*pr_ + G*pr_**4)

    z = A + B*pr_ + (1.0 - A)*exp(-C) - D*(pr_/10.0)**4

    return z

@np.vectorize
def zvdw(pr_, Tr_):
    A = 0.421875*pr_/Tr_**2     # 0.421875 = 27.0/64.0
    B = 0.125*pr_/Tr_           # 0.125 = 1.0/8.0

    z = 9.5e-01
    erro = 1.0

    while erro >= 1.0e-06:
        c2 = -(B + 1.0)
        c1 = A
        c0 = -A*B
        f = z**3 + c2*z**2 + c1*z + c0
        df = 3.0e0*z**2 + 2.0e0*c2*z + c1
        zf = z - f/df
        erro = abs((zf - z)/z)
        z = zf

    return z

Z = zvdw(Xpr, YTr)
fig = plt.figure(1, figsize=(7, 6))
ax = fig.add_subplot(projection='3d')
surf = ax.plot_surface(Xpr, YTr, Z, cmap=plt.cm.jet, linewidth=0, antialiased=False)
```